# What is the mathematical description of the optical curve a flat shape takes from a close perspective?

Tags: geometry

If you look at a square from far away, all the edges look perfectly flat, but if the square is something like 2 feet by 2 feet, for example, and you get close enough to it, you can see that the edges all curve. If you align your face with the center of it, the top edge curves downward on the left and right side, and the bottom edge curves upward on the left and right side.

Is there any sort of function or equation which describes the shape of this curve? I'm sure there must be, but my googling hasn't brought me anything.

I'm not sure what the appropriate tags for this question are, apologies.

Comment: Who is to say that the shape isn't still a perfect square - and all you are facing is an optical illusion?

Comment: The phrase "two-point perspective" comes to mind. (Or is it just one point when the two vanishing points are diametrically opposed?) Projective space also sounds related.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not math but brain psychology. It is caused by the failure of our brains to correct the "non-linear" distortions when they are too extreme. Different person can perceive the curve differently.

Comment: @achillehui I believe any physical optical system in our sort of reality is forced to have a curved perspective on these sorts of lines, and that it's not just a human brain thing. Think about it: if you're looking at a long rectangle that extends to the left and the right, and you're looking at the closest point to you, it must become optically smaller as the shape extends to the left, and it must become optically smaller as the shape extends to the right, and it must be optically largest at it's closest point to you.

Comment: @achille hui is right. "Projective geometry" which is the domain in which your question can be settled make straight line segments appear as straight line segments. When you say in your last comment that they become smaller and smaller, that's right, but they remain (straight) line segments. You will get more complicated curves if you consider the perspective through what is called a ["fish-eye" lens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisheye_lens).

Comment: if the rectangle gets smaller into the distance on the left and right sides, then either the top line has to curve or the bottom does. Two straight lines couldn't make a rectangle become smaller into the distance, two straight lines can only either be parallel, or interscct at exactly one point. @JeanMarie . That's my understanding anyway.

Comment: But whether the question is about the brain or about optical physics, either way I still think there's got to be a mathematical equation or description of it.

Comment: I would say that the question is about our "optical system + brain".